# OpenCv 3.4.1 FaceRecognizer not work in Java . exception when create an object

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition, opencv3.1

i'm trying to make face recognition using OpenCV 3.4.1 library , and i have a problem when make a "FaceRecognizer" object or anyone of its sub-classes . 
after i make an object . this exception apper :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create_1()J
at org.opencv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create_1(Native Method)
at org.opencv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(LBPHFaceRecognizer.java:54)
at facereco.FaceDetectorLive.<init>(FaceDetectorLive.java:43)
at facereco.FaceDetectorLive$3.run(FaceDetectorLive.java:239)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

everything in the library is working except this class :( 
exception throws when compiler reach this line

```
LBPHFaceRecognizer faceRecognizer =LBPHFaceRecognizer.create();
```

Edit :
i found that opencv3.4 don't has org.opencv.face package so maybe its from it ... how can i get it ?;